# Interpreting X-ray diffraction data

Tags: physical-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, crystal-structure

So I've got my data for some x-ray crystals of small molecules of Ag, Cu,... I was curios to know what the best way to determine what type of lattice each of these atoms may have?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific.  What kind of diffraction do you have?  Is this a homework problem?

Comment: Specifically, is this data from an area detector where the crystal is rotated about one axis only, is it from a simple detector (no spatial resolution) attached to a 3 or 4 circle goniostat, or is it film data from a precession camera?

Answer (score 2):

Your question has no sense – sorry.

You talk about a few small molecules (with coinage metals) but ask about lattice type for atoms. Atoms in molecular crystal have no their own lattice. Lattice describes how your molecule are aligned in 3D-space.

Assuming that you have a single crystal data then in the beginning of experiment your X-minion (that's the person that took X-ray data for you) has already found the cell parameters and then usually also Bravais cell. To be sure that selected lattice was right whole data set need to be collected, the data have to be integrated and then using *Lattice exceptions* (*see* International Tables for Crystalography Volume A,  2.2.13. Reflection conditions) you can tell what lattice type you have. If you do the same for glide planes and screw axis exceptions then eventually you will find space group.

Comment: X-minion... That is the best term ever